# Как спарсить первую страницу поиска Google

Tags: php, парсер, google-search

Нужно парсингом (можно cUrl) получить самую первую страницу поиска гугл по конкретному запросу, мне нужно получить только вот эту информацию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал просто cUrl , но гугл не дает и отвечает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это обойти и получить нужную информацию?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'site:vk.com';
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36";
$ch = curl_init ("");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$query);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match_all( '#<div id="resultStats">(.+?)</div>#is', $output, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches[0][1]);
```

Comment: вы пробовали его запускать? тоже самое... 403

Comment: @Денис а по коду видно что я его не запускал? У меня результат есть: `string(87) "Результатов: примерно 42 500 000<nobr> (0,13 сек.)&nbsp;</nobr>"`

Comment: вы запускали видимо на локалке? на сервере выдает NULL , и 403

Comment: А чем по вашему отличается локалка и сервер? правильно - средой. Если запустился у меня на локалке, запустится и на моих серверах. Если у вас не запускается на сервере, проблема с сервером.

Comment: @Денис `/home/development/public_html/test.php:13:string 'Aproximativ 39.900.000 rezultate<nobr> (0,18 secunde)&nbsp;</nobr>' (length=66)`

Comment: у меня обычный vps. не пойму в чем проблема(

Comment: @Денис Возможно гуглу не нравятся ваши айпишки, попробуйте через прокси.